# Broadcast Receivers - Whatsapp and similar services

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, whatsapp

I can't find an answer anywhere. I need to know if there is a broadcast receiver for Whatsapp message just like SMS and Phone calls broadcast receivers. If not, is there a way to perform certain action when messages are received on applications like Whatsapp?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14907818/6028746