# Listen to incoming Whatsapp messages/notifications

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-notification-bar, android-broadcast

I'm working on a notification based app, for which I need to listen to incoming notifications. I've been able to listen to incoming calls, SMS, mail etc. I have no clue how to listen for pings or messages from friends on Whatsapp via code. Can this actually be done? If so, how? Can [Accessibility Service](http://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html#create) be used for this, using Package Name as "com.whatsapp"?

Comment: whatsapp is your on app or third party ?

Comment: whatsapp is a third party messaging/chat app. I don't think it can be done, do you? ^^^

Comment: Using NotificationListenerService we can easily do this. check complete demo code http://www.androiddevelopersolutions.com/2015/05/android-read-status-bar-notification.html

Comment: @ Mukesh Y this only work on API18 and above.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was able to do this using [Accessibility Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService) . Using this, you can listen to all notification on the notification bar. I listened to application-specification by adding the package name to the Accessibility Service `service info` , which in this case was `com.whatsapp`. I couldn't read the messages, but I get notified whenever a message arrives.

Comment: Can you mute whatsapp notification sound and set a custom notification according to the sender of the message?

Comment: @frankish : Absolutely.......NO
you can not show custom notification for different users, through your app, but to mute Whatsapp is impossible unless you have made whatsapp

Comment: @sanjeev mk  using accesbility code can i find either user has recieved messages or recieved images /audio files

Comment: @sanjeev could you provide an example please? Thanks

Comment: @sanjeev can you please share your code how you have implemented this?

Comment: The link is broken!

Comment: here is the correct link : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService , suggestion edit queue is full

Answer (score 14):

### Aug 11, 2020 Update

You can use [`NotificationListenerService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService) to listen for notifications and get  contents.

Here's example implementation in Java:

```java
public class NotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = "NotificationListener";
    private static final String WA_PACKAGE = "com.whatsapp";

    @Override
    public void onListenerConnected() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Notification Listener connected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        if (!sbn.getPackageName().equals(WA_PACKAGE)) return;

        Notification notification = sbn.getNotification();
        Bundle bundle = notification.extras;

        String from = bundle.getString(NotificationCompat.EXTRA_TITLE);
        String message = bundle.getString(NotificationCompat.EXTRA_TEXT);

        Log.i(TAG, "From: " + from);
        Log.i(TAG, "Message: " + message);
    }
}
```

To enable the service insert the following code snippet into `<application>` tag on AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<service
    android:name=".NotificationListener"
    android:label="@string/notification_listener_service"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

To intercept notifications, you need to request a special permission. Here's the code which you can use to open settings page where user have to allow the app to listen to incoming notifications. On my project I placed it in `MainActivity.onCreate` method.

```java
startActivity(new Intent(ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS))
```

If you need to check whether or not the notification listener permission is granted using the following code snippet:

```java
private boolean isNotificationServiceEnabled(){
    String pkgName = getPackageName();
    final String flat = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
            ENABLED_NOTIFICATION_LISTENERS);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(flat)) {
        final String[] names = flat.split(":");
        for (String name: names) {
            final ComponentName cn = ComponentName.unflattenFromString(name);
            if (cn != null) {
                if (TextUtils.equals(pkgName, cn.getPackageName())) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

### Old answer

I listened to incoming WhatsApp message notifications with the help of this 2 parted article which you can read it from [here](https://medium.com/@vanshikaa937/a-complete-guide-to-accessibility-service-part-1-c00387230019).

1. Configure AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<!-- AndroidManifest.xml -->
<service
    android:name=".MyAccessibilityService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="My application"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
        android:resource="@xml/serviceconfig" />
</service>
```

2. Create a new file called `serviceconfig.xml` in */xml/* directory.

```xml
<!-- serviceconfig.xml -->
<accessibility-service
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
    android:canRequestEnhancedWebAccessibility="true"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:packageNames="@null"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"  />
```

3. Create a new `MyAccessibilityService` class which extends `AccessibilityService`.

```java
@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
        System.out.println("onServiceConnected");
        AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
        info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED;
        info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_ALL_MASK;
        info.notificationTimeout = 100;
        info.packageNames = null;
        setServiceInfo(info);
}

@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED) {
        if (event.getPackageName().toString().equals("com.whatsapp")){
            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
            if (!event.getText().isEmpty()) {
                for (CharSequence subText : event.getText()) {
                    message.append(subText);
                }

                // Message from +12345678

            }
        }
    }
}
```

4. It's ready. Now you can customize the service for your needs.

> Note: Because accessibility services are able to explore and interact with on-screen content, a user has to explicitly enable services in Settings > Accessibility. *[More details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12336085/7616528)*

#### Note

To send replies to received notifications [check out this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57306364/7616528) answer.

Comment: ok so i have to get the deleted msg only,  how to do that in your case it will fetch all incoming whatsapp msg

Comment: @SunilChaudhary whatsapp hides notification if message was deleted so you can listen for notification state changes and detect if it dismissed by whatsapp or user. I'm not sure about that.

Comment: I have implemented this but it only logs "message from XXX"

Comment: @newbieee I updated the answer with additional details, please check it

Comment: I'm using the notification listener service but I couldn't able to identify if the notification is from a group conversation or not in android 6 [API 23]. can you help me with this?
Here is the detailed Question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/63913290/9944838

Comment: @Vijay unfortunately I can't.

Comment: I am using notification service but problem is that after rebooting the device it does not start what i have to do please help me  [here is my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559125/notificationlistenerservice-not-working-after-device-boot-complete)

Comment: @prototype86 check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58362719/how-can-i-start-android-application-on-device-boot

Comment: thanks. it works perfectly for me. is it possible to get a sent file link?

Comment: @hassanmoradnezhad I'm not sure about that. But you can try decrypting whatsapp database (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856874/get-all-messages-from-whatsapp). I'm not sure if this is legit or not but it might help to achieve what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Unless Developers of that app intentionally share a service , a content provider, or intentionally send out public broadcasts of events, or expose a custom broadcast registering system, there is no legitimate way in android to listen to internal workings of a third party App. App isolation is designed in Android for a very important reason: **security**.

Comment: Well, I was able to do this using Accessibility Service. Check my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Accessibility events only catch incoming notifications event, not when they are updated. For now, WhatsApp notifications don't display the message, only the sender. The message is then added by the WhatsApp app with an update, which can't be caught by the accessibility service.

You will only have something like "1 new message from XXX", but that may be sufficient to your needs.

Comment: no .. if u recieve one message , then it will show that message .. if u receive 2 or more messages .. then it will show as u said

Comment: What is the better way to do this?

Comment: is there a way to read all messages from WhatsApp notification?

Comment: @Nicolas LUCAS can we get number message of sender?

Comment: @RizwanAhmed yes you can. Whenever a message is delivered to your phone a meta is also sent. All of the information is contained in that meta including the phone number and the sender name. You can use a broadcast receiver to fetch that broadcast.

Comment: @Han and how do we retrieve that meta. I mean which type of broadcast receiver do i have to register. Can you please explain a little more.

Answer (score 2):

See below example to catch whatsapp notifications:

```
public class Notifier extends AccessibilityService {


@Override
public void onCreate(){
    //Toast.makeText(this,"Oncreate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    // Set the type of events that this service wants to listen to.  Others
    // won't be passed to this service.
    Toast.makeText(this,"Service connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_ALL_MASK;;
    info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED ;

    // If you only want this service to work with specific applications, set their
    // package names here.  Otherwise, when the service is activated, it will listen
    // to events from all applications.
    info.packageNames = new String[] {"com.whatsapp"};
    info.notificationTimeout = 100;

    setServiceInfo(info);

}

@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

    if(event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED) {

            Toast.makeText(this,"Notification Catched", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

And don't forget to set permission from settings>Accessibility in order to access the system events. Allow permission from settings .

check this link

[accessibility service is not started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087758/accessibility-service-is-not-started)