# How to read all the coming notifications in android

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

How to read all the coming notifications in android. Is it possible to use the broadcast receiver to listen the incoming notifications and the ability to read the notifications information.

Comment: You can have a look at the AccessibilityService, see http://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html#create or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540394/listen-to-incoming-whatsapp-messages-notifications

Answer (score 29):

First you must declare your intent to receive notifications in your manifest, so that you can get the `android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE` permission.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service android:name=".NotificationListener"
         android:label="@string/service_name"
         android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Then create a `NotificationListenerService` class and override the `onNotificationPosted` function.

For more information, read the developer reference here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html

Also look at this simple example application for implementation guidance: https://github.com/kpbird/NotificationListenerService-Example/

Comment: Note: This works but does not work for the text field of the Stacked Notifications.

Comment: This example is not working for me i have a permission for notification but still its not showing any list

Comment: Say, is it also possible this way to convert all notifications to be ones without heads-up notification

Comment: is it possible to read already existing notification or just new that will come?

Comment: it is working in marshmallow but error in 8.0 with notificationChannel

Answer (score 12):

Using **NotificationListenerService** we can easily read the notification of all application. Check complete demo code [**here**](http://www.androiddevelopersolutions.com/2015/05/android-read-status-bar-notification.html)

Comment: this permission is only available to system apps

Answer (score 2):

You need to do like this in onNotificationPosted in order to get all messages

```
if ((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)){
        Parcelable b[] = (Parcelable[]) extras.get(Notification.EXTRA_MESSAGES);

        if(b != null){

            for (Parcelable tmp : b){

                Bundle msgBundle = (Bundle) tmp;
                content = content + msgBundle.getString("text") + "\n";

            /*Set<String> io = msgBundle.keySet(); // To get the keys available for this bundle*/

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Android provides `android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE` which  you can use to get the notification information.

In your AndroidManifest.xml, declare a service like this:

```
<service android:name=".AppNotificationListenerService"
    android:label="@string/service_name"
    android:exported="false"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Create a class named `AppNotificationListenerService` and extend it from NotificationListenerService

```
class AppNotificationListenerService: NotificationListenerService()
{
    override fun onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification?)
    {
        super.onNotificationPosted(sbn)
        // Query information from sbn using methods like:
        // sbn?.notification.extras.get(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE)
        // Some other keys include EXTRA_TEXT, EXTRA_SUB_TEXT
    }
}
```

You also need to make sure that your application has permission to see all notifications. For that, you can use the below code:

```
val componentName = ComponentName(packageName, AppNotificationListenerService::class.java.getName())
val notificationManager =  getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
if (!notificationManager.isNotificationListenerAccessGranted(componentName))
{
    val notificationAccessSettings: Intent =
                Intent(Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_DETAIL_SETTINGS))

    notificationAccessSettings.putExtra(
                Settings.EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_COMPONENT_NAME,
                componentName.flattenToString()
            )

    startActivity(notificationAccessSettings)
}
else
{
    Log.d(LOGGER_TAG, "App has notification access")
}
```