# Is it possible to determine programmatically whether navigation is in active state or not on Android in Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation

Is it possible to retrieve whether there is any current navigation running in google maps or not?
Suppose my app launches google maps,but i don't to launch if google navigation is in active state. Can we get this state..?

Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe [ths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212992/how-can-i-check-if-an-app-running-in-android) would help? If the application is running, most likely it's active, otherwise the OS would close it out.

Comment: Hi Andy, Actually i don't want to check whether google maps app are active or not, i am particularly concerned about Navigation activity in google maps.

Comment: you got the answer ? i am also looking for the same.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a bit tricky and depends heavily on another application's behavior.
There are 2 different approaches comming to my mind without any guarantee:))

1. Acquire Notification Access permission and check if Google Maps is showing any notification related to navigation or not (which is a little bit sensitive asking user giving you this permission and may not work if user had prevented the Google Maps from sending notifications, but who does that?) You can take a look at this [How to read all the coming notifications in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16757878/how-to-read-all-the-coming-notifications-in-android)
2. Acquire Accessibility Permission and record user's behavior all the time, and when you've seen google maps in current activity, set a flag telling you that navigation was running or not (this permission is very sensitive and I don't suggest it also I guess it takes more effort)
   https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service

Also, you might be able to do something using App Usage permission but I can't think about any tricky solutions using this. You can also check for some broadcasts that Maps might send while starting/ending navigation, but I don't think it does.

Finally, I'm not sure if Google Play is fine with what you want to do, I guess checking another application's state is not acceptable in most cases.