# Can i collect application notifications in android?

Tags: java, android

How can i collect app notifications like New message From X,and 
Ienter code here want to parse this data same `Notification:New Message,From:X,App:Messenger`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Notification Listener Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) from android sdk. Check this stack overflow answer for more details [How to read all the coming notifications in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16757878/how-to-read-all-the-coming-notifications-in-android)