# how to listen to whatsapp media downloading process

Tags: java, android

I am planing to develop a new application. 
But before going to code, I want to know if there is a way to know that whatsapp user select to download media. And if there a way to conrol the downloded file!!

Comment: you can check the whatsApp downloaded files, and you can find the last downloaded file in androidd app;
 check path here https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/wp/30034176

Comment: Thank you Berat, I want to monitor the download process from the beginig and after the end. Your solution gave me the last part.

Comment: Hmm, I think its possible, i have an idea about your question, you can check all notification and detect whatsapp download process? whats your think about my solution? check this link;https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16757878/how-to-read-all-the-coming-notifications-in-android

Comment: The problem is that whatsapp doesn't send notification when you chose to download media.