# Is it possible to read Google Maps direction notifications with another app

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-directions-api

I'm extremely beginner in android development, I thought of building Google Maps direction notification listener app using Flutter is that possible

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that but it's only possible in Android not iOS. You'll have to use `MethodChannel`

In order to read notification in Android, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16757878/how-to-read-all-the-coming-notifications-in-android)