# Android App for forwarding Whatsapp messages to a Webinterface

Tags: java, android, notifications, whatsapp

I'm developing an android app with java that forwards text messages and incoming calls to a webinterface. That part is working so far - I now want to integrate the same functionality for incoming whatsapp messages. Is there a way to get access to these notifications? For the first part it would be ok if only the number of messages and contact are forwarded.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listen to incoming Whatsapp messages/notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540394/listen-to-incoming-whatsapp-messages-notifications)

Comment: I think this might be answered already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540394/listen-to-incoming-whatsapp-messages-notifications)