# NotificationListenerService not working after device BOOT_COMPLETE

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working with `NotificationListnerService` it is working fine after some time it can not work and specially after device is boot it is not starting i have given all permissions which are required for listner here is my code.

```
public class Whatsapp_listner extends NotificationListenerService
{
 private static final String TAG = "NotificationListener";
 private static final String WA_PACKAGE = "com.whatsapp";

@Override
public void onListenerConnected() {
    super.onListenerConnected();
    Log.i("tag","Listner conneted");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    if (!sbn.getPackageName().equals(WA_PACKAGE)) return;


    long yourmilliseconds = sbn.getPostTime();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
    Date resultdate = new Date(yourmilliseconds);
    String date = sdf.format(resultdate);

    SimpleDateFormat my_time=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
    Date timer=new Date(yourmilliseconds);
    String time=my_time.format(timer);




    String modifiyedUniq = sbn.getUid() + sbn.getId() + sbn.getTag();


    Log.e(TAG, "Notification Key :: " + sbn.getKey());
    Log.e(TAG, "Notification Id :: " + sbn.getId());
    Log.e(TAG, "Notification postTime :: " + time);
    Log.e(TAG, "Notification From :: " + sbn.getPackageName());
    Log.e(TAG, "Notification TikerText :: " + sbn.getNotification().tickerText);
    Log.e(TAG, "Notification Title :: " + from);
    Log.e(TAG, "Notification Text :: " + message);


 

}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

    if (sbn.getPackageName().equals(WA_PACKAGE)){

        Log.i("notifyier", String.valueOf(sbn.getNotification().getSmallIcon().getResId()));
        Log.i("notifyier", String.valueOf(sbn.getNotification().extras.get("android.text")));
        int id=sbn.getNotification().getSmallIcon().getResId();
      

    }

}
```

This is working fine but after some time and after boot completes is does not work and i using `broadcast receiver` to start `ListnerService` but still it is not working

Comment: Please help me for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution for this by just adding some lines of code

```
 @Override
public void onListenerConnected() {
    super.onListenerConnected();
    Log.i("tag","Listner conneted");
    tryReconnectService();
}


 public void tryReconnectService() {
    toggleNotificationListenerService();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        ComponentName componentName =
                new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), Whatsapp_recorder.class);

        //It say to Notification Manager RE-BIND your service to listen notifications again inmediatelly!
        requestRebind(componentName);
    }
}

/**
 * Try deactivate/activate your component service
 */
private void toggleNotificationListenerService() {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(this, Whatsapp_recorder.class),
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(this, Whatsapp_recorder.class),
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```